# simulation theory - how is the sorting only log(p)?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, complexity-theory, time-complexity

In the proof of simulation theory : simulating concurrent write : 
"a p-processors in a crcw algorithm can be no more then log(p)time faster then the best erew algorithm for the same problem"

[image]

can anyone explain me why it takes only log(p) to sort the array by the first component in the simulation proof and not O(plogp)?

Comment: I am not familiar with the proof or concept you are talking about. Please include all the necessary information. But I think this would be a much better fit for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sorting is accomplished in parallel with a log-depth [sorting network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network). The AKS construction is a good example of a galactic algorithm. [Batcher's bitonic sorting network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter) with depth log^2 n is more reasonable in practice.

Comment: I am familiar with it.. but why wont you multiple the time complexity in number of processors (p) ?

Comment: @Shiran Each layer of the network can be performed in parallel with exclusive memory operations. The total work is O(p log p), but the time is only O(log p).

Comment: so in the simulation.. we only compare the time and not the work ?

Comment: @Shiran The claim is about the running time of the simulation as compared to the running time of the system being simulated. Both simulation and simulated system are parallel.

Comment: Would you say that the proof for concurrent reading is almost the same?

Comment: @Shiran Speaking off the cuff here, reading is somewhat trickier because all processors that read the same location need the results, whereas with writing, it suffices for only one write to happen. One way, probably not the most elegant, is to sort the read requests, have one processor execute each nonduplicate, run a [prefix scan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum#Scan_higher_order_function) to distribute each value read to all of its readers, then resort the requests by processor ID to distribute them.

Comment: i didn't get you.. but I might just open a new question if I wont understand. thanx

Comment: @Shiran Open it on cs.stackexchange please :) This is off-topic for SO, but it's such a pain to get things migrated or closed that I just answer anyway.

Comment: could you just tell me why the other processors that read the same location need the results ?

Comment: @Shiran If there's a common write, then all but one of the writes is discarded and none of the processors need be the wiser. If there's a common read, then the value influences the local state of each processor that performed a read, so it needs to be communicated to all of them.

Comment: will it be too much to ask u for an example where you can see the influence of the common read on the processors?

Comment: @Shiran Suppose you're implementing an algorithm to sum an array in parallel. The length of the array, n, is given in cell 0; cells 1..n contain the array. At time 0, each processor i (in 0..p-1) reads cell 0 to determine that it is responsible for summing cells 1 + floor(n \* i / p) inclusive through 1 + floor(n \* (i + 1) / p) exclusive, prior to a phase where these partial sums are combined.

Comment: I think I got you.. so before you can combine the sums we need to wait till all of the processors will finish the first stage...and therefor in the parallel algorithm EREW we will need one processor to update the results... thank you very much :)

Comment: @Shiran `Time = epislon * log p + C ~ O(log p)`